# Python:How to remove file extension from tag name in xml file

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

```
This is my code

from xml.dom import minidom
import os, shutil
os.chdir("E:\\")
xmldoc = minidom.parse('123.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('File') #TagName
print len(itemlist)
print itemlist[0].attributes['name'].value
for s in itemlist :
    shutil.move(s.attributes['name'].value, "E:\\Junk\\") #Moving to another location
```

The above code finds the tag  and gets it value.

My xml file is something like this

```
<File>
   <File name="E:\qwer\abc.exe"/>
   <File name="E:\qwer\xyz.dll"/>
   <File name="E:\pqr\bc.exe"/>
</File>
```

How do I remove the "abc.exe"? Is there any way to search for the extension in the xml and then remove it?
Final xml should be like this

```
<File>
   <File name="E:\qwer\"/>
   <File name="E:\qwer\"/>
   <File name="E:\pqr\"/>
</File>
```

Sorry if my question sound ambiguous

Answer (score 3):

Use [os.path.dirname](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname). It will give you just the directory. The other functions in os.path give you other pieces of the absolute path.

Comment: This is the correct answer after the OP updated his question to clarify.

Comment: This might screw up if the script is run on a UNIX machine but the pathnames are Windows paths.